# create list from values in list dicts based on condition

Tags: python-3.8

I am looking to create a list/np.array for each unique expiry date in the following list of dicts:

```
import datetime as dt

data=[{'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 21, 0), 'strike': 137.0}, 
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 21, 0), 'strike': 137.25}, 
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 21, 0), 'strike': 137.5}, 
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 21, 0), 'strike': 136.5},
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 21, 0), 'strike': 137.0},
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 21, 0), 'strike': 137.5},
      {'expiry': dt.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 21, 0), 'strike': 138.0}]
```

the unique expiry dates I can get like so:

```
exp = np.unique([np.array([d['expiry']]) for d in data])
```

the desired output is:

```
[[137.0, 137.25, 137.5], [136.5, 137.0, 137.5, 138.0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `exp`:

```
[[y['strike'] for y in data if y['expiry']==x] for x in exp ]
```

Output:

```
[[137.0, 137.25, 137.5], [136.5, 137.0, 137.5, 138.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @AllaTarighati's solution, you can also you the `return_inverse` option of `np.unique`:

```
exp,ind = np.unique([np.array([d['expiry']]) for d in data], return_inverse=True)

strike = [[data[i]['strike'] for i,j in enumerate(ind) if j==k] for k in range(exp.size)]
```

Here is a solution without any additional comparisons (`j==k`):

```
exp,ind = np.unique([np.array([d['expiry']]) for d in data], return_inverse=True)

strike = [[] for _ in range(exp.size)]
for i,j in enumerate(ind):
    strike[j].append(data[i]['strike'])
```

Output of `print(strike)` for both sample codes is:

```
[[137.0, 137.25, 137.5], [136.5, 137.0, 137.5, 138.0]]
```